# Cordova InAppBrowser do not open the url externally

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to open an external URL [www.google.co.in](https://www.google.co.in) via cordova InAppBrowser. But the browser is appending this URL to the server and port address. So the end URL which is cordova browser trying to open become [http:localhost:8000/www.google.co.in](http://http:localhost:8000/www.google.co.in)

I'm using the **ionic cordova run browser** command to test this.

> Below is the code (Ionic 5.0.0)

```html
import { InAppBrowser, InAppBrowserEvent, InAppBrowserOptions } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';

declare var window: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  loading: HTMLIonLoadingElement;

  constructor(
    private serviceProvider: ServiceProvider,
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private router : Router,
    private menu: MenuController,
    private loadingController: LoadingController,
    private platform: Platform,
    private inAppBrowser: InAppBrowser) { }

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.menu.enable(false);
    this.login();
  }

  public login() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.openInAppBrowser().then(success => {
          alert(success);
      }, (error) => {
          alert(error);
      });
  });
  }

  public openInAppBrowser(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {  
      var options: string = "location=no,clearcache=yes,clearsessioncache=yes"
      var browserRef = window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open("www.google.co.in", "_blank", options);
      browserRef.addEventListener("loadstart", (event:any) => {
        alert(event);
      });
      browserRef.addEventListener("exit", function(event) {
          reject("Completed");
      });
  });
  }
```

> Here is my app.module.ts

```html
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { PopoverPageModule } from './popover/popover.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { GlobalFunctions } from '../providers/global-functions';
import { AuthGuard } from '../providers/auth-guard';

import { ServiceProvider } from '../providers/service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, PopoverPageModule],
  providers: [
    ServiceProvider,
    GlobalFunctions,
    AuthGuard,
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    InAppBrowser,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a simple mistake. I didn't add `http://` to the URL. It should be `http://www.google.co.in` instead of `www.google.co.in`

Comment: I am facing a similar issue; but at a production setting; where the URL contains http:// . Is there a way to work around this even if http:// is not present?

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs, you need to use this:

```
this.inAppBrowser.create("www.google.co.in", "_blank", options)
```

instead of

```
window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open("www.google.co.in", "_blank", options)
```

References:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/ 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/in-app-browser/